# Problema com negação de comparação de Strings

Tags: java, condição

Uma parte do meu código:

```
// faça: 
do {
    System.out.println("Você deseja sentar na Janela (J) ou Corredor (C) ?");
    opcaoSentar = leer.next();
    // se a opção foi J
    if (opcaoSentar.equals("J")) {
        System.out.println("Venda Efetivada");
        // Preenchendo o lugar com 1
        janela[numeroPoltronaSolicitado - 1] = 1;
        // se não, se o a opção for C  
    } else if (opcaoSentar.equals("C")) {
        System.out.println("Venda efetivada");
        // preenchendo o lugar com 1
        corredor[numeroPoltronaSolicitado - 1] = 1;
    } else {
        // caso n foi nenhuma, opção invalida e vai voltar a pergunta
        // por causa do {do while}
        System.out.println("Opção Invalida !");
    }

    // enquanto a opção de sentar (Janela ou Corredor) for diferente de C ou J    
} while ((!opcaoSentar.equals("J")) || (!opcaoSentar.equals("C")));
```

Acho que tem algum erro nesta parte:

```
while ((!opcaoSentar.equals("J")) || (!opcaoSentar.equals("C")));
```

Porque não estou conseguindo sair do laço (do while) nunca. 
Estou fazendo certo a negação da comparação ?

```
(!opcaoSentar.equals("J")) || (!opcaoSentar.equals("C"))
```

Comment: Você tem ciência de que só vai sair se for digitado C ou J maiusculo ne?

Comment: Claro, mas mesmo digitando, não está saindo

Comment: Está observando o case sensitive? C != c, etc.
leer.next() é o imput do console? O que tem no objeto leer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O trecho com problema é esse mesmo:

```
while ((!opcaoSentar.equals("J")) || (!opcaoSentar.equals("C")));
```

Mude para:

```
while ((!opcaoSentar.equals("J")) && (!opcaoSentar.equals("C")));
```

Porque, conforme a tabela verdade:

```
J    C    !J || !C
0    0    true
0    1    true
1    0    true
1    1    false
```

Só seria `false` se fosse 'J' e 'C' ao mesmo tempo! Com a lógica corrigida, fica:

```
J    C    !J && !C
0    0    true
0    1    false
1    0    false
1    1    false
```

Answer (score 3):

O correto é:

```
while ((!opcaoSentar.equals("J")) && (!opcaoSentar.equals("C")));
```

Que se lê:

> *enquanto `opcaoSentar` é diferente de `J` **e** diferente de `C`*

afinal, você quer que se encerre a operação caso uma das duas opções seja a digitada, e da forma como está, a única forma de sair do laço é sendo igual a ambas, o que teoricamente é impossível.

Vale ressaltar que o `equals` é [case sensitive](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive), e a condição somente será validada caso uma das letras seja digitada em maiúsculo. Se isso não faz muita diferença pra condição, basta trocar para [`String#equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-):

```
while ((!opcaoSentar.equalsIgnoreCase("J")) && (!opcaoSentar.equalsIgnoreCase("C")));
```